# Is there easier way to check for a variadic template type?

Tags: c++

I've got a function

```cpp
template<typename T, typename FuncT, typename ... Args>
static void Submit(Handle<T> handle, FuncT&& funcT, Args&& ... args);
```

`Handle` is a class that contains an index to the data inside some array. This data can be retrieved through a `handle_cast` function.

```cpp
T& data = *handle_cast<T*>(handle);
```

I'm not going to cover this implementation, because it's not related to my question.

`Handle<T> handle` is the main handle to a resource. I'd like `args` to be a mix, sometimes it'd be a handle, sometimes a different data.

`FuncT` first argument is `T&` and the rest of the arguments might be either `*handle_cast<Args*>` if this argument is `Handle<Some Type>` or just `Arg`

I came out with this solution, but I'm not sure if it's correct or maybe it could be done easier.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename FuncT, typename ... Args>
    static void Submit(Handle<T> handle, FuncT&& funcT, Args&& ... args) 
{
    std::variant<Args...> v;
    bool isHandle = std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<HandleBase, T>) {
            return true;
        } return false;
    }, v);

    func(*handle_cast<T*>(handle), std::forward<Args>(isHandle ? *handle_cast<Args*>(args) : args)...);
}
```

Is this solution ok or it can be done easier/cleaner?

Comment: What is the question? You described your implementation, but didn't tell what this should do and what is the problem to solve! I recommend to provide [mcve]. The best version of MCVE is failing test (build failure is also test failure), which you are expecting to pass. You can use this: https://godbolt.org/z/8GEGTK6TM as starting point.

Comment: my question is Is this solution ok or it can be done easier/cleaner?

Comment: This can't work since `v` is valueless! So `std::visit` will throw `std::bad_variant_access`!

Comment: not exactly, it works with a int and a double https://godbolt.org/z/s7fPs9M9d

Comment: Your example only checks the type of the first argument (try passing them [the other way round](https://godbolt.org/z/7ex7o9dGc)). Is this what you want? Are arguments either all handles or all non-handles?

Comment: @MarekR `v` is not valueless. The default consturctor initializes the variant holding the value-initialized value of the first alternative.

Comment: In general case it is possible. If first type do not have default initialization it will be valueless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this (not tested):

```
// Cloned from the standard std::forward
template<typename T>
T&& maybe_handle_forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t ) noexcept {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template<typename T>
T& maybe_handle_forward(Handle<T> h) noexcept {
  return *handle_cast<T*>(h);
}
```

Now you can write

```
func(*handle_cast<T*>(handle), maybe_handle_forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Comment: In his code there is `HandleBase`.

Comment: @MarekR well, I don't know what `HandleBase` is, or how it's supposed to fit into the picture.